# display image and text using division tag rowspan in html

Tags: css, html

I want to achieve the below format which i could easily do it using TD tags.

But if i have to make use of only div tags(rowspan) how is that possible.
Below is the format.
[image]

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I being a stackoverflow member have good knowledge about the guidelines. What i asked i have achieved it using td tag. I had never seen something been done using div tag using rowspan. Trial and error should be posted i know but i dont think we need one here as i know i am just missin out some attribute. :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree, you should be making your own attempts with alternate code and showing us that...and it seems several other agree with me.

Comment: I also agree with @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for?

```css
.row {
   display: block;
   border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
} 
.row > img.img {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 0;
}
.row > a.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #338899;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.row > span.description {
  color: #555555;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://assets.rollingstone.com/assets/images/story/taylor-swift-cancels-thailand-concert-due-to-political-turbulence-20140527/20140527-taylorswift-x624-1401220626.jpg" class="img" />
  <a href="#something" class="title">Taylor swift</a>
  <br/>
  <span class="description">This is a singer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: On target. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

use css float

```
<div style="float:left;width:40px;"><img /></div>
<div style="float:right;width: calc(100% - 40px);">
   <h2>Juno Temple</h2>
   <p>Actress, ....</p>
</div>
```

or you can use flexboxes

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.class1 > div{
  display:inline-block
}
.class1 > div:nth-child(2){
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
p{margin:0px}
</style>
<body>

  <div class="class1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:125px;">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Juno Template</p>
      <p>Actres, Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this it's working.